# Customize SOAP request send from Windows 8 application

Tags: web-services, soap, windows-8, wsdl, windows-runtime

I am consuming a WSDL in a Windows 8 app. I need to customize the SOAP request like

New SOAP Request:

```
</ns0:Header>
<ns0:Body>
<ns0:Request xmlns:ns0="http://www.ABC.co.il/2004/01/RetrieveEntityDetails/EntityDetailsRequest">

</ns0:Request></ns0:Body></ns0:Envelope>
```

Current SOAP Request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>

</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_XmlRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_Xml xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<requestDoc>
</requestDoc>
</RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_Xml>
</RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_XmlRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How will I change the **namespace** and set a **request** tag inside the body tag.

Code:

```
Client = new EAI_RetrieveEntityDetailsXP_ServiceSoapClient();
            Client.RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_XmlCompleted += Client_RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_XmlCompleted;
            XElement requestData = GetRequestData();

            using (new OperationContextScope(Client.InnerChannel))
            {
                // Create a custom soap header
                var msgHeader = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("myCustomHeader", string.Empty, "myValue");

                // Add the header into request message
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(msgHeader);

                Client.RetrieveEntityDetailsXPOP_XmlAsync(requestData);
            }
```

Comment: Can you change WSDL and regenerate stubs?

Comment: Can i consume this SOAP service using HttpClient or a webclient?

Comment: You can of course, SOAP runs on top of HTTP.

Comment: Can you give me a sample for the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually used HttpCleint to call this service by using following code. Using this we can generate the SOAP request as desired.

```
string soapString = ConstructSoapRequest();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", SOAPActionUri);
                var content = new StringContent(soapString, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
                using (var response = await client.PostAsync(Uri, content))
                {
                    var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return soapResponse;
                }
            }


private string ConstructSoapRequest()
        {
            return String.Format(@"<ns0:Envelope xmlns:ns0='http://www.cellcom.co.il/2004/01/std-headers'>
<ns0:Header>

</ns0:Header>
<ns0:Body>
<ns0:Request xmlns:ns0='http://www.cellcom.co.il/2004/01/RetrieveEntityDetails/EntityDetailsRequest'>


</ns0:Request></ns0:Body></ns0:Envelope>", 100);
        }
```